# Is there a way to forward unknown land line callers to a specific number in a manner similar to nomorobo?

Tags: phishing, phone, scam

My parents are getting up there in age and recently, my dad asked me about a message on his answering machine from "Apple" saying his account was "compromised". After having educated him on phishing calls, I'm somewhat exasperated that he thought the message was authentic, so I had an idea to manually screen calls for him that aren't from a whitelist.

I looked through the features from his landline voice provider to look for an unknown caller forwarding option, but there does not appear to be a way to forward calls from callers not on a whitelist.  You can only forward specific callers or all callers.  Nor did I want to enable the 'accept selected callers' feature because there's no way to screen legitimate calls, including calls *from* 911.

I set up nomorobo for my parents about a year or so ago (but it doesn't seem to block spoofers like the "Apple" caller) and I was wondering if there was some way to do something similar (such as a service or some device or process), but instead of working from a list of known scam numbers and block them, I'd like it to check the caller against a whitelist I set up and if not on the whitelist, forward the call to me and allow me to decide whether to let the call through or not (e.g. press 1 to add the caller to the whitelist and forward the call back to my dad - or 2 to blacklist them & hang up). Ideally, I would be able to do this either while my phone is ringing based on the caller ID or even after having picked up and spoken to the caller.

Note that they have the ability to see caller ID info on their TV (though I don’t know if that can be used to accomplish what I’m going for here).

As a person with elderly parents and increasing phishing on the elderly, it seems like such a solution would be popular, at least for this niche group.  I found a service in the UK called "Fuss Free Phones" that has operators that essentially do what I'm proposing, but they're shutting down (probably because it's a bad business model to employ real-person operators to handle today's scam volume).  But if you crowd-source the "operators", to those who actually care about the person being called, maybe it could work.

Comment: If you are asking for a service to do that, such questions are off-topic here. If you are looking for a *process* to accomplish what you state in your title, then that might be more on topic, but your title does not appear to match the body.

Comment: I guess I'm asking for either a service or a process, though admittedly, it didn't occur to me that creating a process on my own was a possibility. I do not wish to post anything off-topic, so I'm willing to reword or remove as you suggest. I've never posted anything in this stack before. I joined because it seemed the most appropriate stack for the question. Incidentally, I'm not sure I see the difference between the title and post, so perhaps you could clarify the discrepancy?